# Degree sequences of split graphs

Tags: graph-theory

We say a graph $G $ is a *split graph* if its vertex set can be partitioned as $A\cup B $ with $A $ a clique and $B $ an independent set.

If $G $ has vertices $v_1,\ldots,v_n $ with degrees $d (v_1)>\ldots  >d (v_n) $ then $(d (v_1),\ldots ,d (v_n))$ is its *degree sequence*.

We were given the following theorem that links these two concepts:

> $G $ is a split graph iff the degree sequence $d =(d_1,\ldots,d_n) $ of $G $ satisfies $$\sum_{i=1}^m d_i - \sum_{i=m+1}^n d_i=m (m-1),$$
>   where $$m=\max\{i : d_i\ge i-1 \}. $$

---

My question concerns the significance of this $m $, does it hold any meaning on its own? In particular, the specific line of the proof I do not understand is this:

> Let $G $ be a split graph and $(A,B) $ its partition into a clique $A $ and independent set $B $, such that the size of $A $ is maximal. If $A $ or $B $ is empty then the result is obvious.

Why is this obvious? I suspect it has something to do with the degree sequence... I can see that if $A $ is empty then the degree sequence is $(0,0,\ldots,0) $, and if $B $ is empty then the sequence is $(n-1,n-1,\ldots,n-1) $, but how does this help me?